# Run-Time Error Type '13' mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I've inherited an old Excel-VBA model at work. I'm running this program to calculate loss on a portfolio of loans. The program works fine for a loan portfolio up to 500 loan items, but starts throwing up "Run-Time Error Type '13' mismatch" when I load a larger portfolio with more than 500 items.

```
Public Sub generateLossDistribution()

....

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim p As portfolio
    ' Creates a new portfolio object and reads it
    **Set p = New portfolio**
```

The error message crops up in the "**" code line. FYI, "portfolio" is a user defined object/class module. Since the code works for fewer loan items, could this error be due to increased array size (when bigger portfolio gets loaded)? The portfolio has about 30 fields for each loan items. Is there a limit on the array size, which I can expand?

Apologies of being very vague since I'm just a beginner and the model code is too huge to be uploaded to make any sense.

Thanks

Comment: I thought that error is generated because some cells have different cell formats?

Comment: You should look in the `Class_Initialize` procedure in the `portfolio` class module; that procedure contains the code for initializing every `portfolio` object. Step through with the debugger (setting a breakpoint on the first line of that procedure, and stepping through with F8), and someone here can be of further help.

Comment: You might find the following VBA Option setting useful: from VBA program, Tools menu -> Options... menu item -> General tab -> Error Trapping section -> Break in Class Module radio selection.  This gives more information about exceptions in class modules, by having the debugger stop sooner.

Comment: As this happens after a number of iterations rather than immediately means you might need to go check that objects are being properly disposed of.